# How do I double up the weights of CountVectoriser from SCIKIT for TFIDF matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have tf-idf matrix being generated from text file which I have. I want to give more importance to some vocabulary term.
I have written the code below. How can I double up the weights of the specific vocab terms. Do I need to double the count or just multiple the the weights of TFIDF by 2. I want to increase the importance of some terms from the d

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words="english")
term_freq_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(vectoriser.mydoclist)
# print "Vocabulary:", count_vectorizer.vocabulary_

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf.fit(term_freq_matrix)

tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(term_freq_matrix)
print len(count_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can double either the TFIDF or the count, it is equivalent.

In your case, I would do something like

```
position = count_vectorizer.vocabulary_['the_important_word']
tf_idf_matrix[:, position] *= 2.0
```